# PDE wave equation $u_{xx} + u_{xt} - 20u_{tt}$ = $0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

PDE wave equation $u_{xx} + u_{xt} - 20u_{tt}$ = $0$, with $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$ and $u_t(x,0) = \psi(x)$.

I wonder what's the general way to solving wave equation like this one. Because I found two solutions from different website and two solutions are different as well.

The first solution from this link https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1516/math4220/Solutions%20to%20assignment%202.pdf is $u(x,t) = \frac{1}{9}[4\phi(x + \frac{t}{4}) + 5\phi(x - \frac{1}{5}t)] + \frac{20}{9}\int_{x - \frac{1}{5}t}^{x + \frac{1}{4}t} \psi(s)ds$

And the second solution here http://faculty.smcm.edu/hamoon/M411F14/PDEF14H2Soln.pdf gives $u(x,t) = \frac{1}{36}\phi(\frac{4x + t}{4}) + \frac{5}{36}\int_{0}^{\frac{4x + t}{4}}\psi(s)ds + \frac{35}{36}\phi(5x - t) - \frac{5}{36}\int_{0}^{\frac{5x - t}{20}}\psi(s)ds$

They looks equivalent but I can't tell why at this moment, any suggestions?

Comment: The method is the same in both cases, leading to the same solution, but the second one has three errors. (Note that we don't recover the initial conditions in the second formula, as $u(x,0)\neq \phi(x)$ for it)

Comment: Thanks, so as long as the the initial conditions is a function, then we can't recover into it? What I mean is, I found in his previous example,when $u(x,0) = x^2$, he can set the initial condition and solve for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.   I'm referring to the second link and the question above of $u_{xx} + u_{xt} - 20u_{tt} = 0$.

Comment: I meant that a straight way to see that the second equation is wrong is that for $t=0$ is not $\phi(x)$ as should be. Of course, with the two functions for the initial conditions we can get the particular solution: it is the first in your post!